# Failed to create layout cache. The return code of the layout creation is: 15605

Tags: visual-studio, cmd

### Trying to download Visual studio community 2017 offline installer via cmd using this command

"D:\visual studio 2017>vs_community.exe --layout D:\VSCOMMUNITY2017"

### But after 22.7gd downloaded i got this error

"Error: Package 'Win10SDK_10.0.14393.795,version=10.0.14393.79513' failed to create layout cache. The return code of the layout creation is: 15605."

How can i fix this error.

Comment: That is a [know issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/30834/win10sdk-failed-to-offline.html). Also check [this possible solution](https://codedocu.com/Details?d=1588&a=9&f=54&l=0&v=d).